# Does the World Health Organization have the power to impose sanctions?

Tags: united-kingdom, china, sanctions, covid-19, who

In the last couple of days, WHO officials have [criticised](https://www.lbc.co.uk/radio/presenters/matt-frei/coronavirus-ex-who-boss-questions-uks-herd-immunit/) the UK government's approach to the COVID-19 pandemic, describing the government's reliance on developing herd-immunity amongst the British population, and apparent reluctance to put in place quarantines as "ridiculous".

China has also been criticised for its initial response to the virus, which the Financial Times [describes](https://www.ft.com/content/fa83463a-4737-11ea-aeb3-955839e06441) as a "cover-up", and which US national security advisor Robert O'Brien [says](https://www.axios.com/china-coronavirus-cover-up-wuhan-robert-obrien-7febd3fb-533c-4df6-bd39-ac5c0ae1c284.html) "cost the world community two months" in terms of preparation for the disease. This would appear to be in breach of the [International Health Regulations (2005)](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/246107/9789241580496-eng.pdf;jsessionid=56B11B63495AC2E87B13FE2A600CC62D), Article 6 of which states that:

> Each State Party shall notify WHO, by the most efficient means of
>   communication available, by way of the National IHR Focal Point, and
>   within 24 hours of assessment of public health information, of all
>   events which may constitute a public health emergency of international
>   concern within its territory

Given the criticisms above, does the World Health Organization have any powers to either enforce health recommendations such as quarantines or lockdowns, powers to punish or sanction countries that refuse to comply with said health recommendations, or powers to punish countries that breach their obligations under the IHR?

I have been able to find [this article](http://america.aljazeera.com/articles/2015/10/22/health-sanctions-against-countries-misguided.html) which describes a panel which investigated this in the wake of the ebola crisis, but I can't find more information about the results of this investigation.

Comment: The UK is still a permanent member of the UN security council. It can *not* really be forced by any UN institution.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder good point; applies to PRC as well of course. I'm still interested in knowing if sanctions could be brought in theory though.

Comment: What exactly is the WHO going to do, block medical supplies and personnel from entering the infringing country?  Is there any sanction they can apply that wouldn't be totally counterproductive to their grievance and mission?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian [This article](http://america.aljazeera.com/articles/2015/10/22/health-sanctions-against-countries-misguided.html) shows that punitive measures were investigated in the wake of the ebola crisis; I can't seem to find more on that investigation though

Comment: @CDJB: You should mention that article from your last comment in your question body.

Comment: I object strongly to linking to a paywall article which such an inflammatory claim as *China coverup*.  We don't know exactly how well/badly China handled the early outbreak, so any definitive claim that it was a coverup should be openly viewable if posted on SE.  Otherwise we are running into the same rumor-mongering as *Chinese diplomats claims that the US military brought it in*: https://www.cnn.com/2020/03/13/asia/china-coronavirus-us-lijian-zhao-intl-hnk/index.html

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I think that objecting to pay-walled articles is ill-advised; the majority of scientific articles and academic research material that is referenced in the best answers on this site is paywalled. Maybe something to raise on meta though. [Here is an alternative article.](http://theconversation.com/chinas-coronavirus-cover-up-how-censorship-and-propaganda-obstructed-the-truth-133095)

Comment: @CDJB I would agree, in general.  However, this is not an obscure academic concern, and if there are non-paywalled credible sources and investigations backing up such a contentious allegation then those should be strongly prioritized.  If you can't find any others, then that might be an indication that the article is not as solid as you might think.  3-4 weeks ago I tried Googling up any terms indicating a spread before Dec 27th and found very little to go on.  The mass of covid-19 pages is going to make that progressively harder to search for, but nothing clear emerged then.

Comment: And having read your alternative article, it relates to known facts - the centralized CCP's aversion to bad news from below and its shaky governance model.  It doesn't however point to anything like a *"two month delay"* which I find highly dubious and adds little to your, otherwise valid, question.  Best we know is that people got sick starting mid-December and the situation was not recognized immediately.  as Italy shows, there is no need for intentional coverup or willful bad management.  The doctor being sanctioned is unforgivable, but is a political issue, not a strictly medical one.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The two month delay quote comes from a different article to the FT link, and is a quote from US national security advisor Robert O'Brien. I don't think that article is paywalled, nor do I think I've misrepresented it. His comments have also been widely reported outside of that article.

Comment: @CDJB then that really ought to become a question in its own right *Did China delay the recognition of the threat?* rather than be a "fact" cited in your question.  Right now there's a lot of spin by the US administration re. covid-19 so I would any statement by any member of the administration with a large grain of salt, esp. as it relates to China.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I haven't represented it as a fact, but as a quote. I think the use of quotes from politicians and their advisors to contextualise questions is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **WHO officials have criticised the UK government's approach to the COVID-19 pandemic**

Actually the quoted criticism does not come from the WHO, nor from a current employee of the WHO. It comes from

> Professor Anthony Costello, ex-director of maternal and child health at the World Health Organisation

The criticism is of the claim that the UK government should

> "just let 60% of the population get it"

These appear to be the words of a radio presenter not a published policy of the UK government.

The UK's Health Secretary recently said Herd immunity is not the policy of the UK government.

> “Herd immunity is not our policy. It’s not our goal. Our goal is to protect life and our policy is to fight the virus and protect the vulnerable and protect the NHS. And that’s what we’re doing. Now there is a, of course there’s a scientific debate around scientific concepts, but I want to be absolutely crystal clear that we will do what is necessary to protect life,”

So the premise is questionable.

---

The subject of herd immunity and the 60% figure came from an interview with the chief scientific adviser to the UK government. He was apparently speaking about the conditions for a potential resurgence of COVID-19 next winter and beyond.

---

> **Does the World Health Organization have the power to impose sanctions?**

Not really, not of the sort the question seems to suggest.

The WHO did impose sanctions on a news-media organisation that leaked information in advance of a publication date. WHO banned the organisation from its press conferences for two weeks.

Any UN member state can apply for membership of the WHO. It seems likely the WHO can, as a sanction, expel a member from the WHO. I suspect only the UN itself could expel a state from the UN.

In the past, the WHO has been associated with criticisms of punitive sanctions on countries as hampering the objectives of the WHO. The WHO seems to generally aim to assist rather than punish countries.

Like any individual or organization, the WHO can advocate for or against a sanction. As a UN specialized agency it is likely to be listened to by the UN assemblies. As I understand it, it does not have the *power* itself to commit the UN to sanctions.

It is normally UN member states who would apply and enforce punitive sanctions following a resolution of the UN security council of which the UK is a permanent member with veto rights.